# #include errors detected, can't compile an Arduino project using Visual Studio Code [intelliSense]

Tags: visual-studio, arduino, intellisense, include-path

I'm using Visual Studio Code, Arduino, C and intelliSense plugins. I simply put a DHTNEW library folder into my project one and created an empty .ino sketch, when I try to include  and "dhtnew.h" intelliSense starts to give me include errors.
My `c_cpp_properties.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\libraries\\LiquidCrystal\\src"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "path": [
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                    "C:/MinGW/include/*",
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\libraries\\LiquidCrystal\\src"
                ]
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=6",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 3
}
```

Errors:

```
LiquidCrystal.h: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\libraries\\LiquidCrystal\\src"
cannot open source file "Print.h"

mysketch.ino
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (.ino path) will be provided by the Tag Parser.
cannot open source file "Print.h" (dependency of "LiquidCrystal.h")
cannot open source file "dhtnew.h"
```

When I click the yellow light bulb both on `<LiquidCrystal.h>` and/or `"dhtnew.h"` it says `Edit "includePath" setting`

I've tried adding `"${workspaceRoot}"` to the `c_cpp_properties.json` but it won't help. Obviously it won't compile:

Output:

```
[Starting] Verify sketch - my_sketch.ino
[Warning] Output path is not specified. Unable to reuse previously compiled files. Verify could be slow. See README.
Looking for library 'user32'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying user32.dll
Found library 'user32' at user32.dll
Looking for library 'shell32'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying shell32.dll
Found library 'shell32' at shell32.dll
Looking for library 'Ole32'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying Ole32.dll
Found library 'Ole32' at Ole32.dll
Sto caricando la configurazione...
Sto inizializzando i pacchetti...
Sto preparando le schede...
Sto verificando...
d:\Antonio\..\my_sketch.ino:11:20: fatal error: dhtnew.h: No such file or directory

 #include "dhtnew.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
[Error] Exit with code=1
```